# Low Poly Style Fire Tutorial/Tips

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, particles

the help I got last time was so great I figured it was time to reach out to the community again haha. I am trying to make a lowpoly style campfire. I've got the logs done but now I am trying to figure out how to make the fire. I don't know what it is, maybe its the tags i'm using to search google, but I can't find a single tutorial for making low poly stylized fire. Not a single one. I'm a newbie with blender so I am not really sure where to begin. If anyone could offer some tips or even a link to a tutorial i've managed to miss I would be very grateful. The fire won't be animated but used for a still so it needs to look great. I'd love to be able to figure out how to add sparks to it too.. I've seen a few photos online of some great looking fires, but no tutorials anywhere haha.

Thanks everyone. As far as what i've got, so far i've got nothing but the logs made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest, low-poly fire I can think of is the same setup done for trees and plants in many video games: Setup a plane textured with a fire image PNG (with transparency) and create duplicates that you rotate on the Z-axis.

This tutorial can serve as a starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dsP7N3l7kY

A different style with the same principle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkc-0YUz-Y4

Here is another quick an easy one that can be combined with ones above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYxb8F5moUo

This last one is about making solid-looking low poly trees, rocks and grass: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtO9maU709k

Finally, it doesn't hurt to lean about particles, they can be simple or complex, realistic or stylized and can even enhance the low-poly ones with sparks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLjwN_JqUGU